# display the data in html table using jQuery or php based on th value

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a database table

EmpID   TrainingID   Date        Status

100          5      8/13/2015    Present

101          5      8/13/2015    Absent

102          5      8/13/2015    Present

I need to display this table data in the following form

```
<table>
  <tr>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>100</th>
  <th>101</th>
  <th>102</th>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>8/13/2015</td>
  <td>Present</td>
  <td>Absent</td>
  <td>Present</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

How to do this using either jQuery or php so that it compares the th value and adds in the td

Comment: Did you tried something? Please update the code what you are using..

Comment: This are very basic php works. Lots of examples are given in google. Go get this answer you should help yourself.

Comment: Please provide an [mcv](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  example

Answer (score 0):

Use JQGrid for showing values in gridview from db